# SQLCipher security against multiple access attempts (Android)

Tags: android, sqlcipher

So, the CommonsWare book seems to suggest (at location 30091) that SQLcipher has many protections against a user copying the database and manually trying many different password to guess the correct version.  Can anybody elaborate on such security features?  Does the database lock-down after maybe like 30 consecutive attempts or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anybody elaborate on such security features? Does the database lock-down after maybe like 30 consecutive attempts or something?

No, but it uses 64,000 rounds of PBKDF2 by default. Quoting [the Wikipedia article on PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2):

> PBKDF2 applies a pseudorandom function, such as a cryptographic hash, cipher, or HMAC to the input password or passphrase along with a salt value and repeats the process many times to produce a derived key, which can then be used as a cryptographic key in subsequent operations. The added computational work makes password cracking much more difficult, and is known as key stretching.

Basically, the attacker has two choices:

1. Try things like dictionary attacks (e.g., testing against a list of common passwords). The PBKDF2 rounds add overhead for each check, such that cracking the passphrase will take inordinate amounts of time, for all but the weakest passwords.
2. Bypass PBKDF2 overhead and try attacking using generated derived keys directly. In this case, there are far too many possible keys to try, so again it becomes impractical to find the desired key.

Answer (score 4):

It is the type of encryption used.  SQL Cipher uses 256-bit AES encryption.  This form of encryption is extremely secure against brute-force attacks (i.e. programtatically attempting attempting to guess the encryption key by trying every possible value).

[This article](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279619) does a nice job of describing just how secure AES is. To quantify this, the article states:

> If you assume: Every person on the planet owns 10 computers. There are 7 billion people on the planet. Each of these computers can test 1
>   billion key combinations per second. On average, you can crack the key
>   after testing 50% of the possibilities. Then the earth's population
>   can crack one encryption key in 77,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
>   years!

Comment: cool thanks.  interesting to have an estimated value for the time to decrypt an arbitrary database.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLCipher design and security features is described in detail [here](http://sqlcipher.net/design).  The source code is also available [here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher) for review.